# Bidirectional template class dependencies c++

Tags: c++, templates, dependencies, forward-declaration

The problem is that class A depends on class B and vice versa. The compiler will complain abount an unknown type. The usual solution is to forward-declare the classes. But how to declare template classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took me a while to find a solution so I thought i could make somebody else's life easier by posting a "template" here.

```
// Header A.h
template<class z, class w = float>
class B;

template<class x, class y = double>
class A
{
    B mb;
}


// Header B.h
template<class x, class y = double>
class A;

template<class z, class w = float>
class B
{
    A mA;
}
```

Furthermore you are able to change the optional parameter in the template declaration.

Comment: Saying B* or A* doesn't mean anything because the full type is `A<something, something>*`. A template name by itself isn't a type. Also, identifiers beginning with an underscore, two underscores, or an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the compiler/library implementation by the standard.